# Ubuntu 13.10 Won't Recognize [or connect] to my Galaxy S3 [Android]

Tags: usb

When I connect my Galaxy S3 to my laptop which is running Ubuntu 13.10, it will not detect the Android device. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try to use [AirDroid](http://airdroid.com/). It is very easy, cross-platform and you will access everything (internal card..etc). No matter in what mode the mobile is (MSC or anything). Search for AirDroid in the market and install it in your phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Android setting, search for USB Connection Mode, set the connection mode to MSC. Ubuntu should be able to recognized the micro SD card from your Android device and mount it automatically.

*Note: You can't access internal storage while in MSC mode.